# How to use awk and sed to count number of elements in a column

Tags: bash, awk, sed

There are some emails in my email account's inbox:

```
12:00 <harry@hotmail.com>
12:20 <harry@hotmail.com>
12:22 <jim@gmail.com>
12:30 <clare@bbc.org>
12:40 <harry@hotmail.com>
12:50 <jim@gmail.com>
12:55 <harry@hotmail.com>
```

I would like to use command line (`awk`, `sed`, `grep` etc.) to count the number of emails I received from different people.(change all the minute to :00) How can I make it?

I prefer the result like:

```
Number of email     time          From
   3                12:00      <jim@gmail.com>
   4                12:00      <harry@hotmail.com>
   1                12:00      <clare@bbc.org>
```

Appreciate for your help!

Comment: You can get the number of occurences of each line with `sort | uniq -c`.

Comment: why do you just add a column and do not notify any of the answerers? Try to show your attempts and provide feedback.

Comment: sorry, I am fresh on this forum, how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to do it with `awk`

```
awk '{a[$1]++} END {for (i in a) print a[i]"\t"i}' file
4       <harry@hotmail.com>
1       <clare@bbc.org>
2       <jim@gmail.com>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use `uniq` after `sort`:

```
$ sort file | uniq -c
      1 <clare@bbc.org>
      4 <harry@hotmail.com>
      2 <jim@gmail.com>
```

You can also get the header using `printf`:

```
$ printf "Number of email\temail\n%s\n" "$(sort file | uniq -c)"
Number of email email
      1 <clare@bbc.org>
      4 <harry@hotmail.com>
      2 <jim@gmail.com>
```

We initially have to `sort` the file in order to `uniq` to work properly. From `man uniq`:

> Filter adjacent matching lines from INPUT